# Bucle de incrementos entre rangos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

Tengo los siguientes Array's(abajo), y necesito imprimir en incremento los rangos de posiciones que allí se encuentran, me explico, en la posición 0 de array1 se encuentra el 10 y en el array2 se encuentra el 15, necesito que incremente en uno y luego empiece desde el numero que está en la posición 1 de del array1 ejemplo:

```
var miArray = [ 10, 20, 40, 65 ];
var miArray2= [15, 26, 44, 71];
```

esto debería imprimirme:

```
10,11,12,13,14,15,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,40,41,42,43,44,65,66,67,68,69,70,71
```

Quise intentar con unos ejemplos que busqué en Internet pero ni siquiera me acerco a ello.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo necesitas dos `for` anidados asi:

```js
var miArray = [ 10, 20, 40, 65 ];
var miArray2= [15, 26, 44, 71];

for (var i=0; i<miArray.length; i++) {  
  for (var j=miArray[i]; j<=miArray2[i]; j++) {
    console.log(j);
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, intentaba hacerlo con una funcion, pero veo que es mas facil así